# How can I tell a model reached the optimal parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, optimization, model-selection, supervised-learning

Aside from stacking more models, If I want to know if I have arrived the best possible single model(the best parameter), is there anything/process I can tell?

Assume I made n-degree of polynomial features and I have done a grid search with k-fold CV and picked the parameter combination with the highest score, how can I tell if I reach the global optima but not stuck wilt local optima.

Comment: this is an open research topic

Comment: You can't, most algorithms employ some sort of local optimization technique so there is no way of knowing what the global optimum is.

Comment: Seeing that this procedure doesn't even necessarily give you a true local optimum, you cannot. The good news is that you rarely need the global optimum, but a model that predicts sufficiently well for the task at hand. And that can be shown by verification of the optimized model (often called validation in machine learning).